# What could cause a texture not to function correctly when orbiting a model?

Tags: texturing

Super new to 3d modeling and Blender but I'm having an issue where if I orbit my model the texture doesn't function correctly.

Almost like weird pixelation or something sorry I'm not sure what the proper terminology is.

Any assistance to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Weird Pixelation of texture(that is supposed to be a solid red color)]

Comment: What should the texture look like? Could you edit the question and provide an image of  the texture, maybe describe the desired result. It seems you have double overlapping geometry, but it's hard to tell from the info provided.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the quick response. its supposed to be a solid red color! Thanks!

Comment: To reiterate first comment If you provide some screenshots of mesh, material settings etc or the blend file this becomes less of a guessing game... Not even sure what you specifically  mean by _" when I orbit my model"_ TBH.  Please [edit any new details into question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/182741/edit)

Comment: Looks like z-fighting. Any chance you have duplicate faces?